# make dash open windows on the monitor you click from

Tags: dash-to-dock, gnome-dash

On ubuntu 20.04 (with gnome), how do you control where a window will open when an application is launched from the dock?

I'm using dash-to-dock and have the dock on both monitors.  Some applications (like the terminal) seem to always launch on the same monitor as the dock I am clicking on.  This is what I want.

Other applications (like chrome and thunderbird) sometimes open on the other monitor and then I need to drag them back to the monitor I started on.

I've checked "Isolate workspaces" and "Isolate monitors" in the dash-to-dock settings and don't see anything else that looks like it would help?  Am I missing something?

I saw some post about making a given application always open on the same monitor, but that is not what I want.

Is there a way to have applications always launch on the same monitor the launcher was clicked on?

Comment: Nearly 3 years on and not a peep - :(.  I was hoping to find an answer to something I believe everyone would want.  I'm going to have to look into KDE (or some other distro altogether) and see if this is solved there.